# Android collapsible rows in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an Android newbie. I'd like to create an activity with collapsible rows. The closest component I've seen is ListView. I'd like something where I click a row, and it collapses to reveal more data.

So, each row would be like a title/caption(kind of like the various headings on a newspaper page with stories under each header) that would collapse when clicked on to reveal more info.

Is there any sample code or tutes you guys can point out to me?

Comment: Have you looked at ExpandableListView? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. That should do it